# Using click event handler prevents tooltips from displaying on hover

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using chart.js, I've defined an onClick event handler for my chart and now tooltips don't appear when the mouse hovers over a bar, only when I click the bar.

My code looks like this:

```
events: ['click'],
                    onClick: function (evt, info) {
                            console.log(evt)
                            console.log(info)
                        }
                    }
```

How can I get tooltips to display on hover again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add the `mousemove` event also. This way you tell the browser to listen to mousemove event for the tooltip.

If you just specify `click` event then the chart will not respond to all other events like `mousemove` events.

Try this:

```
      events: ['click', 'mousemove' ],

         onClick: function (evt, info) {
              console.log(evt)
              console.log(info)
        },
```

You can look here ( [link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html#event-option) ) for more details regarding the chart.js events.